# Using id for association vs the model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Just a philosophical question i did not get answer by googling

Which one is better in rails. I am leaning towards second one is there any functionality we are missing because of the first choice.

```
employee.manager_id = manager_id
```

or

```
employee.manager  = Manager.find manager_id
```

My biggest problem with directly assigning the id is that the manager may not even be valid(i.e. it may not be a valid id) but do we we need a table lookup for that?

Comment: Why do you `Manager.find manager.id` when its equivalent to just `manager`?

Comment: It's possible to have foreign key for `manager` other than `manager_id`, if, for example, you have namespaced models like `User::Manager`. In this case table for manager would be `user_managers` and foreign key `user_manager_id`, but association still may be named `manager` (`belongs_to :manager, class_name: User::Manager`). Thus, you can assign to `manager` attribute and rails will figure out actual foreign key, so you don't have to know foreign key - only association name

Comment: @OlegAntonyan it looks like you have a good start to an answer, there...